# ¿Como crear botones que ejecuten una acción en bot de telegram con python?

Tags: python, telegram

Tengo un bot hecho en telegram programado en backend con python. Necesito que las instrucciones que estan en funciones de python se ejecuten a traves de botones, bien sea dentro del chat o en el menu.
por ejemplo, el siguiente codigo:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['input'])
def input(message):
    texts = message.text.split(' ')
    try:
        user_id = texts[1]
        first_name = texts[2]
        last_name = texts[3]

        insert = 'insert into usuarios (user_id,first_name,last_name) values (%s,%s,%s)'
        val = user_id,first_name,last_name
        sql.execute(insert,val)
        mydb.commit()
        
        bot.reply_to(message,'Saved!')

    except:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, """Error! Data Not Saved!. """)
```

Se necesita un boton para cuando se pulse se ejecute la instruccion `/input` y pida los datos.
Un ejemplo de lo que necesito, son las siguientes imagenes:

[image: Ejemplo de botones]

[image: Segundo ejemplo de botones]